# Run a file within exe with vbs

Tags: dynamic, vbscript, exe

I'm trying to run a hta in an exe file using a launcher.
The launcher is selecting the system32 mshta to open the hta, as windows defaults to the 32bit mshta even on 64bit systems.

I have made it like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe page.hta"
```

This does not work, I also tried

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe " & CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory &"\page.hta"
```

This works if I do not pack it.

I have made a hta, a txt with commands for the hta, a launcher to make sure the hta is opened via system32 and a dll for the scripts to work. i need all of this to be in a single clickable file, so my users cannot mess it up.

Comment: What do you mean by " i need to have it as a single runnable file" ?
Please explain more your aim !

Comment: I have made a hta, a txt with commands for the hta, a launcher to make sure the hta is opened via system32 and a dll for the scripts to work. i need all of this to be in a single clickable file, so my users cannot mess it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your launcher is 32 bit so you are in that subsystem.

Both 64 bit programs and 32 bit programs think they are in System32.

To force 64 bit access to System32 from 32 bit use the folder name SysNative.

```
c:\windows\sysnative\mshta.exe
```

will run the 64 bit HTA from the 32 bit environment (it will cause an error in a 64 bit environment).

In 32 Bits

```
c:\windows\system32 = C:\Windows\SysWOW64
c:\windows\sysnative = C:\windows\system32
```

In 64 Bits

```
c:\windows\system32 = C:\Windows\system32
c:\windows\sysnative = Error
```

Comment: I might not have been clear enough. I'm using a 64 bit system and i have the launcher setup so the mshta that is being used is the correct one already.

My problem is, when i pack it with iexpress, i can't get it to open the hta anymore

Comment: I explained it to you. You were clear enough. My comments only apply to Windows 64. They have no meaning on Windows 32.